# Problema con anclas en HTML

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo un menu el cual al hacer clic en un enlace este me lleva a una sección específica de la pagina, el problema es que que no se visualiza correctamente, es decir, me debe mostrar el titulo de la sección al momento de hacer clic en el enlace y no el contenido.

Les dejo un ejemplo.

```css
.menu{
 background-color: rgba(0,70,0,1);
 height: 50px;
 padding-top: 5mm;
 padding-left: 5mm;
 width: 97%;
 font-family: 'Century Gothic';
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: -2mm;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.menu img{
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 position: relative;
 top: 0.5mm;
}
.menu label{
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}
a{
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition-duration: 0.2s;

}
a:hover{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;

}

.label{
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  font-weight: bold;
}
.seccion p{
 font-family: 'Century Gothic';
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.seccion label{
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}
.seccion h1{
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}
.seccion{

 width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/462/462998.svg">
   <label>Menu</label>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="#seccion1" data-ancla="Seccion1">Seccion 1</a>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<section id="seccion_principal" class="seccion">
<h1>PORTADA</h1>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?<p>
</section>
<br>

<section id="seccion1" class="seccion">
<label class="label">Seccion 1</label>
<br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<br>
<section id="seccion2" class="seccion">
<label>Seccion 2</label>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
```

Como se ve en el ejemplo el enlace, lleva al cuerpo de la sección y no al titulo de ésta.

En mi sitio uso un **`<script>`** para darle una animación de desplazamiento al momento de hacer clic en un enlace.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('nav a').click(function(e){               

        e.preventDefault(); //evitar el eventos del enlace normal

        var strAncla=$(this).attr('href');      //id del ancla

        $('body,html').stop(true,true)
        .animate({
            scrollTop: $(strAncla).offset().top},
            1000);

    });
</script>
```

Pienso que también podría especificar que parte de la sección quiero que muestre al momento de desplazar el enlace hacia la sección destinada, con este **`<script>`** si es que es posible.

Para todas las secciones tengo un primer **`<div>`** que contiene el titulo de la sección.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el menú al ser `fixed` no se considera dentro del flujo normal de la página.  Cuando haces clic en el ancla, el título va hasta el tope de la página y queda oculto detrás del menú.  Puedes compensar el tamaño del menú con lo siguiente:

```
.seccion::before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-top: -70px;
  height: 70px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```css
.menu{
 background-color: rgba(0,70,0,1);
 height: 50px;
 padding-top: 5mm;
 padding-left: 5mm;
 width: 97%;
 font-family: 'Century Gothic';
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: -2mm;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.menu img{
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 position: relative;
 top: 0.5mm;
}
.menu label{
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}
a{
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition-duration: 0.2s;

}
a:hover{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;

}

.label{
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  font-weight: bold;
}
.seccion p{
 font-family: 'Century Gothic';
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.seccion label{
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}
.seccion h1{
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}
.seccion{
  width: 90%;
}

.seccion::before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-top: -70px;
  height: 70px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/462/462998.svg">
   <label>Menu</label>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="#seccion1" data-ancla="Seccion1">Seccion 1</a>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<section id="seccion_principal" class="seccion">
<h1>PORTADA</h1>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?<p>
</section>
<br>

<section id="seccion1" class="seccion">
<label class="label">Seccion 1</label>
<br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<br>
<section id="seccion2" class="seccion">
<label>Seccion 2</label>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Y en vez de eso solo ubico el ancla a una altura menor,por ejemplo entre medio de un `<section>` con otro, porque yo tengo en mi `<section>` un **`background-color`** y con aquello se me ve un espacio grande. Ya que tuve que aumentar esos valores adaptandolo a mi en mi sitio para que se visualice bien.